# ntpd Configured for IPv6, Not Binding IPv6 Port

Tags: centos, ipv6, ntp, ntpd

I have the following /etc/ntp.conf on CentOS 7.4:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf: Ansible managed

# drift file
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift

# restrictions
restrict default nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# preferred servers
server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst prefer
server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst prefer
server 2.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst prefer
server 3.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst prefer

# fallback servers
server 0.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.pool.ntp.org iburst

# listen only on local interfaces
interface ignore wildcard
interface listen 127.0.0.1
interface listen ::1

# Disable the monitoring facility to prevent amplification attacks; see CVE-2013-5211
disable monitor
```

However, I'm only seeing it bind on IPv4:

```
[root@0c6790c4704c /]# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           918/ntpd
```

Here are the logs:

```
Jan 08 01:34:05 0c6790c4704c systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Service...
Jan 08 01:34:05 0c6790c4704c ntpd[918]: proto: precision = 0.064 usec
Jan 08 01:34:05 0c6790c4704c ntpd[918]: 0.0.0.0 c01d 0d kern kernel time sync enabled
Jan 08 01:34:05 0c6790c4704c systemd[1]: Started Network Time Service.
Jan 08 01:34:05 0c6790c4704c ntpd[918]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 65536, initial socket boundary: 16
Jan 08 01:34:05 0c6790c4704c ntpd[918]: Listen normally on 0 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Jan 08 01:34:05 0c6790c4704c ntpd[918]: Listening on routing socket on fd #17 for interface updates
Jan 08 01:34:07 0c6790c4704c ntpd[918]: 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart
Jan 08 01:34:07 0c6790c4704c ntpd[918]: 0.0.0.0 c012 02 freq_set kernel 0.000 PPM
Jan 08 01:34:07 0c6790c4704c ntpd[918]: 0.0.0.0 c011 01 freq_not_set
```

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

check if `/etc/default/ntp` contains `NTPD_OPTS='-4 -g'`

the option `-4` says to the ntpd to only listen to ipv4 .

Answer (score 0):

I had a special use-case: I was running VMs (read: regular systemd init process) in Docker (c.f. `naftulikay/centos-vm`) and the host system did not have IPv6 support enabled.

I found [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/#how-ipv6-works-on-docker) that passing `--ipv6` to the Docker daemon process would enable IPv6 support, so I tried this and got the following:

```
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv6 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network
```

Within the container, `ifconfig` shows no IPv6 address:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7923  bytes 51083816 (48.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6941  bytes 400410 (391.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So, unsurprisingly, if there is no CIDR block associated, IPv6 isn't going to work. I guess read the docs for more info on how to set things up.

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Comment: To my knowledge, no, but when I get the time I'll [hopefully be able to test it](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-time).